How to *Accumulate* Consecutive `scrollBy` Calls with `behavior: "smooth"` for Smooth Scrolling?
Background
I’m implementing a feature where pressing Alt enables scrolling 5x faster, similar to the behavior in VSCode. Below is the relevant code snippet (full code can be found at CodePen):
/**
     * Scrolling speed multiplier when pressing `Alt`.
     * @type {number}
     */
    const fastScrollSensitivity = 5;
    function findScrollableElement(e, vertical = true, plus = true) {
        // -- Omitted --
    }
    /**
     * Handle the mousewheel event.
     * @param {WheelEvent} e The WheelEvent.
     */
    function onWheel(e) {
        if (!e.altKey || e.deltaMode !== WheelEvent.DOM_DELTA_PIXEL) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        const { deltaY } = e;
        const amplified = deltaY * fastScrollSensitivity;
        const [vertical, plus] = [!e.shiftKey, e.deltaY > 0];
        const el = findScrollableElement(e, vertical, plus);
        Object.assign(lastScroll, { time: e.timeStamp, el, vertical, plus });
        el.scrollBy({
            top: e.shiftKey ? 0 : amplified,
            left: e.shiftKey ? amplified : 0,
            behavior: "instant"
        });
        // TODO: Smooth scrolling
    }
    /**
     * Enable or disable the fast scroll feature.
     * @param {boolean} enabled Whether the fast scroll feature is enabled.
     */
    function fastScroll(enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            document.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel, { capture: false, passive: false });
        } else {
            document.removeEventListener("wheel", onWheel, { capture: false, passive: false });
        }
    }

The feature works as expected when using behavior: "instant" in scrollBy. However, switching to behavior: "smooth" causes issues.

Question
The issue arises when I use behavior: "smooth". If scrollBy is called repeatedly before the previous animation ends, the subsequent call seems to interrupt the ongoing animation, leading to inconsistent behavior and slower scrolling speeds.

Is it possible to let the browser accumulate consecutive scrollBy calls instead of cancelling previous ones?
If not, how can I modify my code to enable smooth scrolling without these issues?

I prefer having the browser handle the smooth animations rather than manually calculating and animating via JavaScript.

Attempts

Using scrollBy with behavior: "smooth"

Problem: Consecutive calls interrupt previous animations.


Accessing scrollTop

Problem: When accessed before the animation ends, it returns intermediate values, which makes calculations unreliable.


Smooth scrolling with requestAnimationFrame (considered but not implemented)

I want to avoid handling smooth animations manually if possible.




You will need option #3. You can't control the specifics of the browser's behavior. If you want deviates, you have to implement it yourself (or use a library).

Instead of using scrollBy (which doesn't have as good support on old browsers as scrollTo anyway), you can use scrollTo and manually keep track of the target coordinates by adding each deltaY. Like so (full edited example on CodePen)
const lastScroll = {
  targetX: -1, // keep track of target coordinates
  targetY: -1, // keep track of target coordinates
  time: 0,
  el: document.scrollingElement,
  vertical: true,
  plus: true,
};

// ...

function onWheel(e) {
  if (!e.altKey || e.deltaMode !== WheelEvent.DOM_DELTA_PIXEL) {
    reset();
    return;
  }

  // ... as before

  let targetX = lastScroll.targetX >= 0 ? lastScroll.targetX : el.scrollLeft;
  targetX += e.shiftKey ? amplified : 0;

  let targetY = lastScroll.targetY >= 0 ? lastScroll.targetY : el.scrollTop;
  targetY += e.shiftKey ? 0 : amplified;

  // set boundaries
  targetX = Math.max(0, Math.min(targetX, el.scrollWidth - el.clientWidth));
  targetY = Math.max(0, Math.min(targetY, el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight));

  Object.assign(lastScroll, {
    targetX,
    targetY,
    time: e.timeStamp,
    el,
    vertical,
    plus,
  });
  el.scrollTo({
    top: targetY,
    left: targetX,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}

function reset() {
  Object.assign(lastScroll, {
    targetX: -1,
    targetY: -1,
    time: 0,
    el: document.scrollingElement,
    vertical: true,
    plus: true
  })
}



This indeed works, but still feels somewhat laggy. Also, I've found a bug, which should be easy to fix: if you first alt scroll down, then scroll down for a long distance, and alt scroll down again, it'll "drag you back". Anyway, I think this might be the best result without JS participating in animation frames.

@PRO Strange, I'm not experiencing either of those issues. I don't see any lag and I couldn't get it to drag me back up. I'm curious: why do you not want to implement smooth scrolling with animation frames? It's relatively simple and it might lead to a better result (not tested it in the context of this demo).

When I say laggy, I mean everytime you alt scrolls, the scrolling speed is reset, so it just doesn't feel consistent. As for the bug, it is because normal scrolling won't update lastScroll variable. If you alt scroll down once (step 1), scroll down to the bottom (step 2), and then alt scroll down once again (step 3), the script would calculate step 3's offset based on step 1's offset, which kinda "drags you back". As to animation frames, I'm just being paranoid :)

Oh, I see! Well spotted, thanks, and I fixed that in the code pen. I also fixed another bug I just spotted: it wasn't ensuring the target coordinates were in bounds of the scrollHeight/Width.
As for the resetting of the speed: the browser does this and I'm pretty sure there is no way to get around it without you doing the scrolling as an animation.
